# What does "be like" mean as in "I be like"?

Tags: phrases, sentence

Is it proper to use 'like' in this way: 'I be like "how is this possible"'? Shouldn't it be 'I was like "how is this possible"'?

Comment: If the context is consistent with its being African-American Vernacular English, the use of *be* in lieu of a standard finite form may indicate that the likeness is lasting rather than momentary.

Comment: Context, context, context. Without context, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @RegDwigнt edited

Comment: @Diksha You raised a good point. In "I be like," the verb *be* isn't properly conjugated, according to standard English.  However, if you really want to clean up "I be like," you may have to make another change!  If the sentence is "I am like my cousin -- we're both crazy about fried onions," you're okay.  But if the sentence is "I was like, 'Are you serious?!' " there is still a problem.  In standard English, this would be "I said to him, 'Are you serious?!' "  In a conversation among friends, you don't have to use standard English; but you'll probably want to use it in a job interview!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either the rarely used subjunctive or it's US urban slang for "I feel" or "I said."

In the following sentence

> If **I be like** a melody, it could only be a John Cage sonata.

the verb is in the present subjunctive to indicate doubt or unrealized condition.  But nobody uses this construct today, if at all, and certainly not in conversation.

In urban vernacular, "I be" takes the place of "I am" or "I was" or "I said,"  so "I be like" means roughly "This is how I feel" or "This is what I said."  For a combination, I quote the lyrics of "Blah Blah Blah" by Rich Homie Quan:

> When she try to argue with me
>   **I be like**,  “Blah blah blah blah”

(I hope you don't need me to explain rap lyrics further.)

Part of the point is that it's nonstandard.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What don't you understand about the answer?  "If I be" is a proper but little used subjunctive.  If it's slang, then it means what I said it means, and since it's slang, there's no question of propriety.

Comment: Sorry @deadrat. It was the closest option to "This answer should provide examples or more detail." I do understand what you're saying though.

Comment: No need for an apology.  I just needed to know what you thought was missing.

Comment: @deadrat Your answer was closest to what I wanted. Thanks!